# Does async/await result in blocking code? What can be actual useful scenarios for async/await?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
let x=1;
let p1 = new Promise(function(rej,res){
 fs.readfile('path',function(err,result){
    if(err){
     rej()
    }
    else{
      res()
    }
 })

await p1;
console.log(x);
```

This code seems to block the last operation of console.log(x).....Although it helps in cleaner code for me ....but looks like it degrades performance...what should be the correct way or useful scenario to use async/await?

Comment: A useful scenario for it: you need to use the return value in another query.

Comment: No it doesn't block,  `async / await` is meant to make async code look like blocking code.  But internally the Websites message pump still runs, so if you have multiple promises running, it can make it feel like you are running threads, when in reality your not.  Used correctly it enhances performance, not degrade..

Comment: Degrades performance compared to what?

Comment: Is this a top level await? Or copied from within a function?

Answer (score 1):

`await` will only appear to block code further down *in the same function*. For example, the following would log `x` immediately:

```
const fn = async () => {
    let x = 1;
    let p1 = new Promise(function (rej, res) {
        fs.readfile('path', function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                rej()
            }
            else {
                res()
            }
        })
    });
    await p1;
};
fn();
// .catch(handleErrors) if you want
console.log(x);
```

As would the following, simply removing the `await`:

```
const fn = async () => {
    let x = 1;
    let p1 = new Promise(function (rej, res) {
        fs.readfile('path', function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                rej()
            }
            else {
                res()
            }
        })
    });
    p1
        .then(() => {
            console.log('file read complete');
        });
        // .catch(handleErrors) if you want
    console.log(x);
};
fn();
```

There is absolutely nothing to worry about performance-wise about using `async`/`await` - you just have to make sure your code's logic is set up to carry out the timing you want.

> what should be the correct way or useful scenario to use async/await?

IMO, when you have multiple Promises that you need to wait to resolve before running additional code. The benefit to readability is marginal when there's only a single Promise, but when there are multiple Promises that depend on the prior resolve values, it really starts to shine - at no cost to performance.

Comment: `p1.catch()` is also a good idea here, even if it's a `console.error`, unhanded promise rejections is maybe something to try and avoid.

Answer (score 1):

> This code seems to block the last operation of console.log(x)

The term "blocking" in JS means "Stops the JS engine from doing anything else".

So this doesn't block.

It puts the containing function to sleep and frees up the event loop to run other functions (and handle events, timers, etc) until the promise resolves and a value is available.

This does stop that particular function from continuing until then, but only that particular function.

When the value is available, next time the event loop is free, the function is woken up again, the `await` statement is evaluated as the resolved value of the promise, and the function continues.

This is useful when you need to do something **after** the promise resolves or with the data the promise resolves with.

Normally you would have something like:

```
x = await p1;
console.log(x);
```

Your example where `x` is already known doesn't make much sense.

You shouldn't await the promise if you want to continue the function without waiting for it.

Comment: To add, if you don't await a promise, remember to handle the error `catch()` as it now has nowhere to cascade to.